# Change VS 2015 to use EcmaScript 6?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studios 2015 to write react code. I am trying to understand ReactJs.net as well.

When I made my app.js folder and put this code in

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <h2>User List</h2>
        <UserList />
        <hr />
        <h2>User Details</h2>
        <UserDetails />
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

everything is underlined and I see this message

> "EcmaScrpit6 feature. Your current language level is EcmaScrpit5"

How do I change so I don't get this message anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Old post but here's the answer since this issue does arise now and then: This is a ReSharper error that results from scanning your Javascript code.  If you place the cursor over the code with squiggly red lines under it and press alt-Enter to bring up the ReSharper context menu, you will be offered the opportunity to 'Change to ...', whatever the feature you are using requires, e.g. ECMAScript 2015 or whatever.  Make sure you do not exceed whatever you have configured in your Typescript config (tsconfig.json) compiler options and double-check browser compatibility before you change to a new higher ECMAScript level in your Javascript code.

If you want to manually manage what ReSharper complains about, Click Extensions/ReSharper/Options in Visual Studio to bring up the ReSharper options dialog.  Scroll down to Code Editing->Javascript and click Inspections.  You will see a drop-down with the label 'JavaScript language level:' there.  Select whatever ECMAScript level you want there and save the settings.  Done.